# What is difference b/w modifying and updating in the Elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

I am following Elasticsearch official docs where there is a section on **Modifying Document:** https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.2/_modifying_your_data.html
So I already have a document under `/customer/_doc/1`:

```
{
  "_index" : "customer",
  "_type" : "_doc",
  "_id" : "1",
  "_version" : 1,
  "_seq_no" : 1,
  "_primary_term" : 1,
  "found" : true,
  "_source" : {
    "name" : "ajay"
  }
}
```

Below is the request to "modify"

```
PUT /customer/_doc/1
{
  "firstname": "ajay",
  "lastname": "tanwar"

}
```

`GET` would return the updated document

```
{
  "_index" : "customer",
  "_type" : "_doc",
  "_id" : "1",
  "_version" : 2,
  "_seq_no" : 2,
  "_primary_term" : 1,
  "found" : true,
  "_source" : {
    "firstname" : "ajay",
    "lastname" : "tanwar"
  }
}
```

On the next page of docs, **Updating Documents** https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.2/_updating_documents.html
Below is the request used to "update"

```
POST /customer/_doc/1/_update
{
  "doc":{
      "firstname": "ajay",
      "lastname": "tanwar"
  }
}
```

This also return the same result as "modify".

Two difference I noticed in both of these:

1. "modify" request updates the `_version` on each request. Whereas the
   "update" request keeps the `_version` same
2. "modify" request's response contain `"result" : "updated"` whereas
   the "update" request's response contain `"result" : "noop"`

But few doubts I have: first of all, why the "modify" returns `"result" : "updated"`? Docs itself says it's a modification operation. And why "modify" returns `"result" : "noop"`? What is `noop` BTW?

And if we go logically, modifying and updating are the same thing. What is the purpose of these two different APIs?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you **modify** document, you delete the old document and insert an entirely new document in its place. This is similar to HTTP's `PUT` method, in that it simply replaces the old document with whatever is sent in the HTTP body.

When you **update** a document, you make changes to the old document. Internally, ElasticSearch will *also* delete the old document and insert a new (updated) document. However, this operation should be treated as if it just made changes to the old document. This is similar to HTTP's `PATCH` method, in that it will keep the old document and only apply the changes sent in the HTTP body.

`"result" : "updated"` means changes were made to the ElasticSearch database whereas `"result" : "noop"` (no operation) means nothing happened (probably because the end result after update would've been the same as before the update).

Comment: So, in both the operations, eventually, we are deleting the old version and creating a new one?

Comment: Internally, that is indeed what happens. I've edited my answer to try and clarify the difference in semantics between the two.

Comment: If the answer answered your question, please accept it so the question can be closed. :)